# What are the names of software vulnerabilities?

Tags: exploit, vulnerability, software, exploit-development

In web apps there are vulnerabilities like SQLi or XSS and many more. I heard that for hackers to hack a computer they have to find a vulnerability in a software that is running on an open port.

What are the names of software vulnerabilities, just like web apps have SQLi or XSS? What is the equivalent for computer software, or where can I learn about it?

Comment: I googled your title question and got page after page of lists. Please do some research before posting here.

Comment: And CORS is not a classification of vulnerabilities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many different classes of vulnerabilities that affect software. A comprehensive list would be huge, but some common classes are:

- Memory corruption (stack/heap buffer overflows, misused format strings, use-after-free, double-free, etc.)
- Broken authentication (complete bypass, manufacturer hardcoded password, etc)
- Injection (SQL/SMTP/LDAP/etc. injection, command injection, etc. Just like web.)
- Race conditions (TOCTOU)
- Logic errors (business logic flaws, lack of validation, etc.)
- Privilege escalation
- Broken/weak cryptography
- Many others

Answer (score 2):

There are many, like a buffer overflow or format string bug.

Websites like root-me or ringzer0team have a lot of challenges, you can learn a lot about this subject.

Answer (score 1):

Vulnerabilities are weaknesses in networks or applications.
Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures (CVEs) give a standard naming convention for vulnerabilities of different system technologies giving details of disclosure and ranking. 
REFERENCE ;
https://cve.mitre.org/

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like network penetration testing vulnerabilities. Stack buffer overflow, heap buffer overflow, race condition, denial of service, remote code execution etc.

Comment: No, "network penetration testing vulnerabilities" is not a part of this. No network, and not penetration vulnerabilities.

Comment: software running on a port is a service, therefore it'd may be affected by the issues I mentioned above. An open port with the running service is discovered in a network, so yes vulnerability names he's looking for are related to network security.

Comment: No. Software running on a port does not ***classify*** software issues as network issues. Technology is a stack. Using your logic, if my car gets a flat tire and prevents me from going to work that day when I should have been doing my code review to catch a buffer overflow vulnerability in software that runs on the network, one cannot classify my tire as a network vulnerability. That's not how technology stacks work, and that's not how logic works.

Comment: Interesting because the guy with the upvotes literally mentioned all the same vulnerabilities I did.

Comment: But didn't call them "network penetration testing vulnerabilities" which is my entire point ...